# PGFPlots — custom colors for ticks labels

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

Is there any way to change a color of a single tick label? 
I need some labels to be black and others to be blue and red.

```
\documentclass[png,border=4pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{
   every axis label/.append style ={black},
   every tick label/.append style={black}  
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            xlabel={X},
            ylabel={Y}
        ]  
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There might be more elegant solutions, but you can of course specify all the ticklabels, adding colour to some with `\textcolor{<color>}{<ticklabel>}`, see example below.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=4pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{
compat=1.12
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
      xlabel={X},
      ylabel={Y},
      xtick={0,0.2,...,1},
      xticklabels={0,\textcolor{blue}{0.2},\textcolor{red}{0.4},0.6,0.8,1}
   ]  
    \addplot coordinates {(0,0)(1,1)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The dummy tick label is not ignored if you add a plot with `\addplot` to the `axis`.